Create a config module for ESLint, Prettier, and got import problems
I am working on a config npm module for my personal project. I have realized this repo with a Prettier, ESLint, tsconfig, ...
My config tools repo: https://github.com/Seyrinian/seyrinian-tools
When I am trying to use it in one of my personal projects I am installing the package and I have the config in a index.js file produced by the ts building of my tools repo.
Then I am calling my personal config in each equivalent config files (Prettier, ESLint, ...).
Here is my test repo: https://github.com/Seyrinian/boilerplate-node
When I am trying the pnpm lint command I have the following error:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.4.0

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '~' imported from C:\Users\Utilisateur\Workspace\boilerplate-node\node_modules\.pnpm\@seyrinian+seyrinian-tools@1.0.10\node_modules\@seyrinian\seyrinian-tools\dist\index.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.

It seems it concerns my index.js built by TypeScript on my tools project. But I don't understand why itcan't resolve this import.

It looks like that you are using ~ to link the files.
Replace the ~ with the relative path to your seyrinian-tools package in your project's configuration files. Since it's a local dependency, you can use a relative path like ../seyrinian-tools/dist/index.js (assuming your config files are in the same directory as your project's root).
